# PC drops internet connection every 15 minutes

Tags: wireless-networking, troubleshooting, desktop-computer

About a week ago I got a brand new PC and for the first few days, it worked just fine.

3 days ago it just started randomly cutting off my Internet connection saying "No Internet, Connected" so I would turn off the Wi-Fi button on my PC and turn it back on which makes it work for a solid 15 minutes before cutting off again.

Another issue that I had was a slow connection when Netflix was streaming or the PS4 was on so I called my ISP and they fixed it and I no longer has a slow connection.

I booted up my old PC, plugged in the same wireless adapter and it had no issues there.

So I'm thinking that it might be an ISP issue. If they fixed my slow connection they could fix this? This only happens on my new PC and not on any other device in the house.

Comment: There was a Windows Update that created WiFi issues, however I'm unsure if it applies here, as it sounds like a configuration issue between the dongle's settings and the router, or a driver issue for the dongle on the new PC. General FYI: WiFi network radios should be set to actual channels, never Auto _(2.4GHz DFS channels: `1`, `6`, or `11` ; 5GHz: highest DFS channel available - in the US, channel `157` works best if using with an 80MHz bandwidth; 160MHz has two DFS channels)_

Answer (score 0):

I have personally experienced this on two laptops. They both had a Realtek Network Chipset (not sure that matters) and the problem was resolved by disabling Bluetooth. Bluetooth is often handled by the same chipset as wifi.

Try disabling it. If it resolves the problem, but you need Bluetooth, perhaps a separate Bluetooth USB dongle would give you connectivity without interfering with wifi operation.

Comment: For potential workarounds, see: ( https://superuser.com/questions/1230905/wifi-bluetooth-interference ) In my case workarounds such as those listed there were not successful.