# Bluetooth headphones audio degrade when connected to Computer but only while (5Ghz) Wifi is on

Tags: wireless-networking, audio, bluetooth, headphones, interference

My question is regarding what seems like interference between my Bluetooth headphones and Wifi on my laptop. The Wifi works fine but my heaphones end up crackling worse and worse after a bit of playtime until the audio becomes too disjointed to listen to. I thought they had gone bad but trying them on other devices they work fine and trying a new pair of Bluetooth headphones on my laptop seems to urge out the same problem.

Why I figure it's an intereference problem is because when I shut down my Wifi and try listening to audio the bluetooth headphones work just fine immediately.

[image]

However when I turn on Wifi again and try listening to audio the problem returns and it starts degrading. I've tried out drivers and various troubleshooting before figuring this out, it seems like something is not working ideally between how the laptop connects to bluetooth and wifi.

[image]

Searching for a solution, the closest help I could find was in another SU question thread: [WiFi - Bluetooth interference](https://superuser.com/questions/1230905/wifi-bluetooth-interference)

It seems like a common problem with Bluetooth and Wifi could stem from the settings fixed on the Wireless Lan card. According to the link *Antena Diversity Selection* and *Bluetooth Collaboration* are settings that could have helped if changed, but my Wireless Lan card doesn't seem to have these settings.

[image]

General info:

- My PC: ideapad Gaming 3-15ARH05 Laptop - Type 82EY
- Wifi: Realtek 8822CE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC
- I connect using 5GHz range which seems to be outside of the common Bluetooth range (2.4 GHz)
- The seems to be specifically from my PCs wifi when on as my bluetooth device is connected

Is there some setting I could try out to figure out how to fix this or is there some other way to go about it?

Thank you for any help

Comment: You are seeing signal bleed or feedback caused by the internal components of the hardware.  The feedback has nothing to do with a specific Ghz range.. it is feedback (meaning noise that was not intended) caused (usually) by a poorly shielded electronic component.  There is probably nothing you can do about it.  You got a lemon.  I too have purchased motherboards that ALWAYS whine when "stuff is happening" and there was nothing short of having an EE degree that I could do about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it was a problem with my drivers. I ended up downloading Avast Driver Updater and updating everything from my Bluetooth modules, to the Realtek Audio drivers and even modem/wifi drivers. Somewhere inbetween those updates it has solved my problem.

[image]
[image]