# Bluetooth connectivity issues when connected to Wi-Fi, issues disappear when Wi-Fi is turned off or 5 Ghz Band is disabled

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, bluetooth, network-adapter

I have a Mini PC equipped with a soldered Realtek 8852BE network interface card (NIC), which supports Wi-Fi 6 and Bluetooth 5.2. However, I'm encountering a peculiar issue where enabling the Wi-Fi connection on the PC leads to Bluetooth becoming unresponsive. This issue persists regardless of the type of Bluetooth device connected, including AirPods Pro, a bluetooth keyboard (Logi MX Mechanical Mini), and Bluetooth thermal label printers (Jadens 168BT). The issues that I face are that the devices become completely unresponsive, AirPods Pro have no sound, Label Printer will not connect to PC, and keyboard will have lots of delayed keystrokes and often disconnect. All of these issues seem to go away as soon as I disable the Wi-Fi.

Attempts Made:

1. Updated drivers for the Realtek 8852BE NIC to the latest version (17/01/2024). Updated drivers for Realtek Bluetooth Adapter (22/09/2023). Didn't work.
2. Tried looking for settings such as "Bluetooth Collaboration" and "Antena Diversity Selection" in the driver settings from Device Manager > Network Adapters > Realtek 8852BE Wireless LAN WiFi 6 PCI-E NIC > Properties > Advanced, but these options were not available. I heard of these settings from [this other question on Stack Overflow](https://superuser.com/questions/1230905/wifi-bluetooth-interference).
3. Switched between different Wi-Fi bands (2.4 GHz and 5 GHz)  from same menu in Attempt 2 to mitigate potential interference. Didn't work.
4. Switched from 802.11b/g/n/ax to 802.11b and from 802.11a/n/ac/ax to 802.11a from same menu in Attempt 2. Didn't work.
5. Disabled the "Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)" under Network Adapters in Device Manager.
6. From the same menu in Attempt 2, I disabled the 2.4 GHz band for Wi-Fi, which did not resolve the Bluetooth issue. Disabled the 5 GHz band for Wi-Fi, surprisingly resolving the Bluetooth connectivity issue but resulting in degraded Wi-Fi performance.

Disabling the 5 GHz band unexpectedly resolved the Bluetooth connectivity issue, although it led to degraded Wi-Fi performance due to the forced use of the 2.4 GHz band. This workaround is not ideal, and I need a solution that allows both Wi-Fi and Bluetooth to function properly without compromising performance. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

On another note, I am so confused as to how disabling the 5GHZ band fixes the issue. As from what I know (correct me if I am wrong), Bluetooth and Wi-Fi can both operate at the 2.4Ghz band, but Wi-Fi has the exception of also being able to run at 5Ghz. Disabling the 2.4Ghz Band for Wi-Fi should in theory clear any interference that the Bluetooth radios are facing, except in this case, the opposite occurs, and I can't seem to understand why or how that works.

Additional Notes:

The Mini PC is a NiPoGi AK1-PLUS Mini PC, Intel N100, 16GB DDR4 3200Mhz, 512GB NVME runs on Windows 11 23H2, updated to the latest version. The issue persists even after trying multiple Bluetooth devices and updating drivers. I also believe the Wi-Fi antenna and Bluetooth Antenna are shared, I don't know much about this area, but the NIC is soldered onto the board, and under Device Manager > Bluetooth, I see a device that says Realtek Bluetooth Adapter. If I disable this, I lose Bluetooth functionality.